# Creating user-defined conversions

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I'm trying to create units for meter and kilometer. I want then to sum and convert them accordingly. I know that the boost::units library has already SI system, but I want create all from scratch, because then I need to create my own systems for my projects (so I'm doing this to learn).
My purpose is to declare a "Length" variable that can be modified using units: for example I want to write

```
Length xLength1 = 5350 * Meters + 2 Kilometers;
```

For this purpose, I've created the **length.h** file, containing definitions of meter and kilometer, and at the end I declare the conversion between these two units:

```
#ifndef LENGTH_H_
#define LENGTH_H_

#include <boost/units/base_dimension.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/scaled_base_unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/conversion.hpp>

struct LengthBaseDimension : boost::units::base_dimension<LengthBaseDimension,1>{};

typedef LengthBaseDimension::dimension_type LengthDimension;

struct MeterBaseUnit : boost::units::base_unit<MeterBaseUnit, LengthDimension, 1>{};
template <> struct boost::units::base_unit_info<MeterBaseUnit>
{
  static std::string name()   { return "meter"; }
  static std::string symbol() { return "m";     }
};

struct KilometerBaseUnit : boost::units::base_unit<KilometerBaseUnit, LengthDimension, 2>{};
template <> struct boost::units::base_unit_info<KilometerBaseUnit>
{
  static std::string name()   { return "kilometer"; }
  static std::string symbol() { return "km";        }
};

// I don't want to use scaled_unit because I need this for my real purpose
BOOST_UNITS_DEFINE_CONVERSION_FACTOR(KilometerBaseUnit, MeterBaseUnit, double, 1000.0);

#endif
```

Then I create the file **units.h** in which I define my own unit system

```
#ifndef LIB_UNITS_H_
#define LIB_UNITS_H_

#include "length.h"
#include <boost/units/unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/static_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/units/make_system.hpp>
#include <boost/units/io.hpp>

typedef boost::units::make_system<MeterBaseUnit>::type UnitsSystem;

typedef boost::units::unit<boost::units::dimensionless_type, UnitsSystem> Dimensionless;
typedef boost::units::unit<LengthDimension                 , UnitsSystem> SystemLength;


BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(Kilometer  , SystemLength);
BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(Kilometers , SystemLength);
BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(Meter      , SystemLength);
BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(Meters     , SystemLength);

// Typedefs of dimensions
typedef boost::units::quantity<SystemLength> Length;

#endif
```

At least, I use this header in my main function

```
#include "units.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  Length xLength1 ( 300.0 * Meters);
  Length xLength2 (1500.0 * Kilometer );
  Length xLength3;
  std::cout << xLength2 << std::endl;
  xLength3 = xLength1 + xLength2;

  return 0;
}
```

This projects compiles, but It does not do what I want. When I print the variable xLength2, I obtain **1500 m** instead of **1500 km** or **1500000 m**. The sum is also wrong, because I obrain 1800 m. It's like I consider kilometers as meters and conversion does not work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You define `Kilometer` to be the same as `Meter`. I don't recall offhand what is the preferred way to define `Kilometer` (perhaps there is a different macro), but you can try something like `const Length Kilometer = 1000 * Meters;` (shuffling the order of definitions).

Comment: But in this case I can't write and take value in kilometers, but only in meters. I want the possibility to work with both units, and use both values where needed.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you're using MSVC++ or the gcc, you can replace your `#IFDEF LENGTH_H_` etc guards with `#pragma once` at the top of each header.

Comment: Apparently what you want is a "variant" type of boost quantity. There are some clues here: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/units-quantities-with-system-abstraction-quot-any-lt-length-gt-quot-td2964466.html

Comment: Do you "have" to use boost? There are simpler ways in C++ to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're project is to replicate the Boost library, this seems like an insane way to code a unit system. Template hackery is rarely the best option.

Instead, use a class! Not real code below:

```
class temperature{
   double temp; //always in kelvin
   temperature(double temperature, char unit){
       if(unit=='k')
                temp=temperature
       if(unit=='c')
                temp=temperature+273
    }
 };
```

And so on to implement conversion back to whatever unit you want. Basically you pick a base unit that everything is stored as, and convert to and from that. If you're doing SI, perhaps grams, meters, seconds, kelvin, etc.

Comment: This is not Boost.Units way, thus doesn't answer the question.